# Minecraft Skyblock building down in nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm searching for a way to build down in the nether for skyblock because I hear at y=57 and some other x,z coord you can get blaze to spawn. However, I can't figure out how to build down in the nether. Someone mentioned sand but I have no idea what that means and how it would work. Since all water boils in the nether I'm stuck on how to do this. Note that I play in hardcore mode so falling to place a block all the way down isn't an option. Any other ways?

Comment: My guess is that using sand meant throwing sand blocks below of the platform you are standing on.

Comment: What does that do? Wouldn't that just cause the sand to fall into the void below? I'm not following that.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't see that `skyblock` word. You might want to add this to your title, as some may mark it as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 3 options in my opinion:

1)Acquire a piston. With this piston you can push blocks down. This can be repeated as many times as necessary. (Iron can be obtained by waiting for a iron bar drop from a zombie in a mob-spawner.)

2)Have a watercourse near your over-world portal. Create a down flowing lava-fall and drop down in this to build. Quickly return to the over-world and put out the fire. Rinse and repeat.

3)Plunging to your death whilst placing blocks on the lowest level of your island.

Comment: Problem with piston is that you need iron. In normal single player skyblock you don't have iron. The reason I want the blaze rod is so I can get iron via turning a zombie villager back into a villager, getting 2 villagers and having them breed, then making a village with them so an iron giant spawns so I can then get iron. So chicken and egg with option 2.

Comment: Option one is still an option when you are no on hard mode. An other solution would be fire resistance, but that would be chicken and egg too i reckon.

Comment: Although, swimming down in lava gives you a bit more time to place blocks then it does when you are falling to your death.

Comment: Think I could do that without fire resistance, then run back into portal and get into water to stop the death? Get full again and rinse & repeat? Not sure if the fire would knock me back off the lava scaffolding without resistance.

Comment: If I'm correct the lava would not knock you back, Keep in mind that the teleportation time is also rather long.

Comment: It looks like an iron ingot is a rare drop from zombies. Maybe I just build a mob spawner and wait until I get 1 iron ingot to make the piston and then use that method. Would need redstone too but witches can drop that.

Comment: I think that would be a good thing to do. I will alter my answer also!

Comment: So the piston method is just facing the piston downward and activate it so it pushes a block down and rinse and repeat right?

Comment: Correct, i also changed my answer if you would like to choose it as a final one :)

Comment: Just got my 1 iron drop to start this all!

Comment: @user441521  don't zombies spawn in skyblock?  Last I checked zombies drop iron, as well as carrots and potatoes and I think even beets now. Rare, but if you make mob farm shouldn't take very long

Answer (score 5):

simple solution: piston pushing the cobblestone down.

less simple solution requires the witch to throw fire resistance on herself, you being affected because of standing near her, than running through the portal and lava-scaffolding.

Comment: Problem with piston is that you need iron. In normal single player skyblock you don't have iron. The reason I want the blaze rod is so I can get iron via turning a zombie villager back into a villager, getting 2 villagers and having them breed, then making a village with them so an iron giant spawns so I can then get iron.

Comment: If I go the witch route I think I'd just try to have a witch hit me and the zombie villager with potion of weakness so I can then feed him a golden apple to turn him into a normal villager, but would love to avoid that, but options are looking bad here :(

Comment: `In normal single player skyblock you don't have iron.` If you kill enough zombies, you will get a rare iron ingot drop.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get pistons before getting a villager. You are able to get Iron from killing zombies, but the redstone is a bit trickier. The villager method is definitely the best way to do it, but there is also the possibility of finding a place where a witch is supposed to spawn (witch hut) and kill witches for it. They spawn naturally without huts, but it is quite rare, so that is another option. It shouldn't be too hard to get 1 redstone this way.

As for powering the piston, a button works, which is very cheap. You push the blocks down little by little, then you can make a stone platform to catch everything you need. Good luck to anyone playing now, Skyblock is an underrated game mode. Remember, Skyblock for 1.16 has recently come out, so check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try suicide lava scaffolding and repeat, instead of straight jumping off. Alternatively, for the piston method, remember that iron bars are also a rare drop of zombies. If you have a decent mob spawner set up, you can weaken zombies by a deep fall, while avoiding to kill them. Then you hit them once with your sword to enable the possibility of getting a rare drop. After a while you should be getting an iron bar. You luckily only need a single one for a piston. Witches can provide the redstone for the piston.